# Video playing in background with multiple activities in foreground

Tags: android

Is it possible to have a video playing as a background while an applications activities are in the foreground. I realize you could have a surface view as the lowest z-order element in a layout, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve a new surfaceview for each activity and attaching surfaces to the mediaplayer over and over.

I would like to achieve seamless video playback using MediaPlayer while the user navigates from activity to activity. One solution is to create one single activity that houses the surfaceview and then present the whole application UI using fragments only. This solution isn't the most ideal for what I'm trying to acheive as I'm finding that one single fragment per "screen" is making it hard to define the UI layouts I'm after.

Comment: You can have fragments inside fragments:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29

Comment: thanks, I didn't go this route because my app targets Android versions < 4.2. I didn't realize that you could do nested fragments with the support library

Answer (score 0):

From a layout viewpoint, there is no difference between an Activity and a Fragment (ultimately, each of those just hosts a View).

You can only have 1 Activity visible at a time, so, don't think what you are looking for with this questions exists.

Regardless of how you create your Views (layouts) if you want multiple ones to show up, you will need them to be hosted in a single Activity.